# TabView is all yellow in "preview"

Tags: xcode, swiftui-tabview

I added TabView to my application and it was yellow for some reason in simulator & in preview mode.

[image]

I found a workaround for simulator ( https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669833 ) and fixed this by changing the GPU preferences but can't find how to fix this for preview canvas. Any ideas?

Xcode: Version 12.3 (12C33)

Comment: This seems to happen intermittently in simulator.